# initializing an empty view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

i am trying to initialize an empty view model with a drop down property in it so when it comes to controller, it doesnt give error about the dropdown. Below is the code how I am trying to get it to work but it skips over the foreach loop because the model is empty at the start:

ExampleViewModel

```
public class ExampleViewModel
    {
    public ExampleViewModel()
    {

        ExampleViewModel = new ExampleViewModel();
    }


    public SelectList dropdown{ get; set; }
    public string dropdownvalue { get; set; }

}
}
```

Controller code:

```
        List<ExampleViewModel > integration = new List<ExampleViewModel >();


        foreach (var item in ExampleViewModel )
        {
            item.dropdown= ApplicationService.GetDropdownlist(null);

        }
```

In View my drop down is being called as:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.dropdown, new { @id = "rightlabel" })
<span>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dropdownvalue, Model.dropdown)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dropdown)
</span>
```

is there a possible workaround this so dropdown list gets initialised ?

Comment: The code for your example viewmodel is invalid (I'm assuming it's a typo). The dropdown should be initialised before the view is created, so why don't you just get your dropdown values before you call `View(viewmodel)` in your controller? Where is your loop that gets the dropdown values? I'm not sure why they would be null when it looks like you are populating them (your `return View()` statement should be after the controller code above)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be Initialising a variable that does not exist and not initialising the properties that you actually care about..

```
public class ExampleViewModel
     {
         public ExampleViewModel()
         {
             this.dropdown = new List<string>(); 
             this.dropdownvalue = string.Empty;
         }

         public List<string> dropdown{ get; set; }
         public string dropdownvalue { get; set; }

      }
}
```

That will stop null reference exceptions. I would also not place a SelectList in a view model... a List would be much better.

You should construct the SelectList in your view using the List from the view model... replace List<> with something more appropriate depending on your requirements.

Comment: `SelectList` doesn't have a parameterless constructor - not sure why people use it in models - it's mostly there for the view imo